# How to add animation to "DropdownButtonFormField" (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, animation

How to add animation to `DropdownButtonFormField` in Flutter?

I want to animate the button when it is clicked and open the list of `DropdownMenuItem`.

So, how can I do that?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The base widget doesn't let you customize its animation. To do this you could recode a `DropdownButtonFormField` widget by looking through the original source code and adding your animation wherever you want.